# Angular 12 - Display web api data with variable columns in a table

Tags: html, angular

In my Angular 12 application, I am trying to display data from a web Api in a table, the problem is this data has a variable column length e.g.

```
<ol>
<li>A|B|1234|1255|12445|</li>
<li>A|B|666|58585|</li>
<li>A|B|45|99|456|77|657|</li>
</ol>
```

A & B are always constant but the numbered columns could be any number of columns and it's title is an arbitrary number.

How can I access this variable length column in my application? Usually I'll access A and B like this

```
<tr *ngFor = "let data of DataFromAPi">
<td>{{Data.A}}</td>
<td>{{Data.B}}</td>
<td>{{Data.???}}</td>
```

the web api generates "DataFromAPi"  from a list of Ids on another web page and a dynamically generated SQL script that is dependent on the number of IDs. My application currently has access to this list of IDs.

Comment: Can you give an *exact* sample of the data you are getting from your API in the question - For instance, does the API return an array of arrays OR an array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

this is actually very simple you were onto the right thing

on the unknown constant - the fourth column you list the data like
**data.????** - instead it should just be the **unknown** **const** as a **?** **data?.c** which means it may be there or it may not, on your template you can even write a class if you wanted to highlight it.  just one single question mark allows this to happen - because we are telling angular hey this might be here, but it might not.

likewise if you wanted to tell angular it would always be there data.c! or data!.c.

Comment: Hey, I get a property c doesn't exist error

Comment: its whatever the property that you choose C is just a variable I used for the constant  I apologize for that I thought you understood that.